# Not able to load OS onto MicroSD

Tags: raspbian, operating-systems

So my raspberry pi 3 didn't come with a MicroSD card. That's fine, I had an old Android phone that was just lying around, so I pulled that SD card out of that phone, wiped and formatted it, and tried to load the OS onto this SD card. I used 7Zip to unzip the file onto the card, but it would get 95% complete and it would fail due to lack of space on the card. The card has 8 gb of space and the OS is only 4 gb. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You may wish to use `Etcher` (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/windows.md) as the Raspbian image is now over 4G in size (https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/) and a sd card formatted in fat16 or fat32 can not exceed 4GB. You could also load Raspbian Lite.

Comment: @bstipe He is talking about extracting files, which implies that he's using NOOBS. The last time I checked (a moment ago), all of the files inside NOOBS are less than 4GB. *|* OR he's doing things wrong (extracting the Raspbian disk image into the SD card).

Comment: @Adam We need to know what you're using. Which one of these are you using? https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Comment: @pandalion98 that's exactly what I was doing. I used NOOBs and was able to get everything working. Thank you